# Capture values in a code similar to JSON

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make a tool for one game (Victoria II), the save game (the entire save game hasn't this format, only the part which i intend to use, the rest of save game hasn't any importance now) of Victoria II has this format:

```
 AAA = {
    B = {
        random_text = 1000.00
        another_one = 400.00
    }
    C= { 
        no_importance = 222
    }
    D = {
        random_text = 5.00
        another_one = 10.00
    }

 }
```

How the tool will work? The tool will calculate the GDP of the country AAA (there are 100 countries, firstly i want to calculate the GDP of AAA, but i will want to calculate of every one. The code of every country is three letters in uppercase), the B parameter is the domestic production of some goods (random_text and another_one), the C parameter has no importance, so, the tool will ignore it. The D parameter is the price of some goods (in this case, random_text and another_one, if not mistaken there are 20 goods). So, the tool (in JavaScript) must multiply the production of goods in the country with the price that each goods has, and then make a table with the GDP of every country. The question is: How i can do this with JavaScript? I'm trying to use regexp, [but I'm always failing](https://regex101.com/r/eC7cX4/1), the code captures the parameter C and makes the tool fails. For every country, i want to insert its name in the table and its respective GDP.

Note: In the link above, there are more comments about the working of the tool.

Comment: if you can replace the equal (=) sign with the colon (:) sign then you have a Javascript object which should be much easier to parse.

Comment: @Daniel_L you're right I missed that. I believe that this needs a parser not a pattern matcher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the format you show above is reliable, you could do a quick-and-dirty conversion to JSON via a few calls to `.replace()`, then parse that JSON and process the resulting object as required.

Not sure I understood what you were saying about the GDP calculation, but I *think* you mean that the GDP for AAA would be the sum of each B value multiplied by its corresponding D value, i.e., 1000.00 * 5.00 + 400.00 * 10.00 = 9000.

```
var input = ' /* your input here */  ';

var json = '{'
         + input.replace(/([^\s]+)\s*=/g,'"$1":')
                .replace(/([^{\s])\n(\s*[^{}])/g,'$1,\n$2')
                .replace(/,(\s*})/g,'$1')
         + '}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var output = Object.keys(obj).map(function(v) {
  return {
    country: v,
    gdp: Object.keys(obj[v].B).reduce(function(p, c) {
      return p + obj[v].B[c] * obj[v].D[c];
    }, 0)
  };
});
```

After running the above, the `output` variable will be an array of objects with details in this format:

```
[ { "country": "AAA", "gdp": 9000 }, //etc. ]
```

Expand the following and run it to see it working with three countries:

```js
var input = `AAA = {
    B = {
        random_text = 1000.00
        another_one = 400.00
    }
    C= { 
        no_importance = 222
    }
    D = {
        random_text = 5.00
        another_one = 10.00
    }
 }
 BBB = {
    B = {
        random_text = 111.00
        another_one = 222.00
    }
    C= { 
        no_importance = 222
    }
    D = {
        random_text = 3.00
        another_one = 4.00
    }
 }
 CCC = {
    B = {
        x = 10.0
        y = 20.0
        z = 30.0
    }
    C= { 
        no_importance = 222
    }
    D = {
        x = 1.00
        y = 2.00
        z = 3.00
    }
 }`;

var json = '{'
         + input.replace(/([^\s]+)\s*=/g,'"$1":')
                .replace(/([^{\s])\n(\s*[^{}])/g,'$1,\n$2')
                .replace(/,(\s*})/g,'$1')
         + '}';

var obj = JSON.parse(json);

var output = Object.keys(obj).map(function(v) {
  return {
    country: v,
    gdp: Object.keys(obj[v].B).reduce(function(p, c) {
      return p + obj[v].B[c] * obj[v].D[c];
    }, 0)
  };
});

console.log(output);
```

Comment: I tested it with HTML and jQuery. 
The value of the variable "input", is the value of a textarea. Then the code print in the console the variable "json", the result of this variable was "{"Brazil": {[...]}}", that is, the code insert a "{" before the country code (in the case, the country name)

Comment: The error on the console.log(output) was: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 9 of the JSON data

The value of textarea [is this code](http://pastebin.com/Qy4g5siA), and the code of JS, [is this one](http://pastebin.com/hxPXD3tW)

Comment: You can see the code in my answer works within the self-contained demo I provided. If you're having trouble with other data, please create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net so that I can see it (not) working (pastebin doesn't let me run the code).

Comment: Thanks. I hosted the demo in the [codepen.io](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAPqbZ?editors=1111). [This is the code](http://pastebin.com/Qy4g5siA) which i test.

Comment: The codepen that you've linked to doesn't use the same code that is in my answer. On the line `var json = ` you seem to have removed the `'{'`, and the `+` on the next line, and the closing `+ '};'`. Those bits are required to make valid JSON, and if you put them back it seems to work fine with the data from your link: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pEydJa?editors=1111 (I think those brackets are what you were talking about in your first comment? I don't know why you thought you needed to remove them.)

Comment: Haha, i don't see this mistake so trivial. Thanks for your help, and sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: One more question:
In the notepad has a tool for select the matches of a Regular Expression, i want to match the country parameters. How i can do this, for example:
       $BRZ= { 
       (...)
       }$
I want to capture everything inside the BRZ, and BRZ itself. For better explanation, i want to capture everything between "$" (obviously, there will be no "$" in front of the "BRZ", I enter only for the make the explanation easier)

Comment: I don't know how to write a regex that could deal with an unknown number  of nested brackets. But if you're saying you have a string containing data for multiple countries, maybe you can do something like the following: `(BRZ.*)([A-Z]{3}|$)`, where the first sub match would be the part you want? Alternatively, if the list of multiple countries is in the same format I assumed in my demo, you could use the first part of my code that converts it to JSON and parses it to create `obj`, and then use `obj.BRZ` to get the BRZ data.